# Consuming message with specific routing key?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms

I am new to Rabbit MQ. Read couple of [Rabbit MQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html)

In the mentioned link my question is about below `ReceiveLogs`

```
     channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer)
```

As single queue can hold messages routed with different routingKey.  Say if consumer want to consume message with specific routing key.
Is it possible ? Do i need to publish meesage with single routing key only on specific queue in this case ?

I do not see any method under [Channel API](http://www.rabbitmq.com/javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html)

Comment: Could you please point me where you found this `As single queue can hold messages routed with different routingKey` ? Think I'm missing some context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RabbitMQ producer publishes to `an exchange` not to a `queue` - this decouples producer from the consumer.
Yes, as described [in the official article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html) you can have messages routed with different `routing key` in the same queue, you just need to create `more than one binding for that queue` for this to happen.

Now to directly answer your question: if you want to have one routing key per queue you need to do the following:

for each `routing key` you want consumer to listen to:

- Create a queue
- Call `channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, <your_routing_key>);` only once for that queue.

Comment: Would this be how to achieve "request -> response" via AMQP? I know about replyTo + correlationId but I feel like with correlationId you still have to listen for multiple subscribe messages on the consumer side and check the correlationId (lots of bandwidth). I'm curious if routingKey gets rid of that problem?